# Casper JS for loop not working in evaluate

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Hi I am trying to loop through a node list in an `CASPERJS` evaluate statement like so :

```
var t = this.evaluate(function() {
    var t = document.querySelectorAll('.status');
    var r = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < t.length; x ++) {
        r.push(t[x]);
    }

    return r;

})
```

While the array contains the correct number of entries, only the first contains a dom element, the rest returning undefined?  This also happens if I return the `t` nodelist on it's own.

Comment: The problem isn't in that code. Can you post an [mcve]? (BTW, that code could be `var t = this.evaluate(function() { return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.status')); }` or if you don't want to polyfill `Array.from` on old browsers,  `var t = this.evaluate(function() { return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.status')); }`.

Comment: Hi TJ, I think you missing that it's running in CasperJS, the code works fine in chromes console.

Comment: I understand it's running in CasperJS. But unless CasperJS is fundamentally broken, which I'm sure it isn't, the problem isn't in that code based on the description.

Comment: See the duplicate